# Definition quadratic variation

Tags: stochastic-processes, definition, quadratic-variation

The **definition of quadratic variation** of a stochastic process $Y$ is that $[Y]_t$ for which for each $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that
$$P\left(\left|\sum_{i=0}^{m(\pi)-1}(Y_{t_{i+1}}-Y_{t_i})^2-[Y]_t\right|\geq\epsilon\right)\leq\epsilon$$
for all partitions $\pi$ with $\operatorname{mesh}(\pi)\leq\delta$.

The following 'definition' seems much more natural to me, **is it equivalent**?

For all $t\geq 0$ and almost all $\omega\in\Omega$
$$[Y]_t(\omega)=\sup_{\text{partitions }\pi}\sum_{i=0}^{m(\pi)-1}(Y_{t_{i+1}}(\omega)-Y_{t_i}(\omega))^2$$
I wonder this, because I cannot find a definition of quadratic variation outside the context of stochastic processes, while the above can be defined as the quadratic variation of the *function* $Y(\omega)$.

Comment: No, it's not equivalent...